# Is my solution correct? Obtain the PDE by elimination arbitrary constants $z = a(x+y) + b(x-y) +abt +c$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**The question is obtain the P.D.E by eliminating the arbitrary constants**
$$ z = a(x+y) + b(x-y) +abt +c $$

as per my understanding we have to get rid of $a,b,c$ so what i did was partially differentiate by $x,y,t$

$$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = a + b $$
$$x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = xa + xb $$
$$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} = a - b $$
$$y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} = ya - yb $$
$$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t} = ab $$

now substituting all in given equation we get

$$z =  x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} + t\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t} + c $$

now to get rid of c again partially differentiating w.r.t x

$$ \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} + x \dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} +y\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y} + t\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial t}$$

$$  x \dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} +y\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y} + t\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial t} = 0 $$

is this solution correct???

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but it is $a$ PDE, not $the$ PDE. For instance, $z=a(x+y) + b(x-y) +abt +c$ also is a solution to the PDE $z_x^2-z_y^2-4z_t=0$.